# Need a good, inexpensive app to catalogue journal articles and books

Tags: publications, citations, productivity, reference-managers, library

Like the title says, I'm looking for an inexpensive app or program that can catalogue both journal articles and books. I need something that has or can take input from an ISBN/QR/barcode scanner, and can also do in-line article annotation like Mendeley.

Background: I work at a very small consulting firm. We do IT, custom software, creative services (design and UXD) and user research (theory, strategy and testing). We're just starting to put together a research library, and we quite frankly don't have the money for high-powered library software.

I know I'm probably asking for a magical unicorn here, and if what I want doesn't exist, please tell me. I figured research professionals would have had the most need for something like this; any help you could throw my way would be much appreciated.

-Z

Comment: This sounds like a "[shopping question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/305499)", which are not a good fit for the StackExchange Q&A model.

Comment: Please read the [guidelines](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You may try your luck in [SoftwareRecommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but I doubt your question be applicable for that site too from the way it is framed.

Answer (score 1):

I recomment to meet some librarians and talk with them about your requirements in more detail. There are a lot of software solutions that could fit.

I assume from what you wrote that [Invenio](http://invenio-software.org) could fulfill your requirements. It's an Open Source Software for publications and can be used for repositories and as an integrated library system. Invenio is developed by CERN as a framework and everyone can create its own overlay. I know at least one library using it with RFID but none with bar codes so far. It allows to catalogue all types of publications.